# TextArea in SkinnablePopUpContainer error

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am trying to add a textarea to a SkinnablePopUpContainer, but running it gives me an error.
If I change the textarea to e.g. a label the code runs fine:

```
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer " " width="244" height="150">
<fx:Declarations></fx:Declarations>
<s:TextArea width="98%" editable="false" text="blah"/>
```

**Error:**

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
>       at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()
>       at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::rawChildren_getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2187]
>       at mx.managers::SystemRawChildrenList/getChildIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemRawChildrenList.as:181]
>       at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/getFormIndex()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:1956]
>       at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/findTopmostForm()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:1933]
>       at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/updateProxyImageForTopmostForm()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:2172]
>       at spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mobilecomponents\src\spark\components\supportClasses\StyleableStageText.as:1510]
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:957]
>       at mx.managers::PopUpManagerImpl/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManagerImpl.as:382]
>       at mx.managers::PopUpManager$/addPopUp()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\PopUpManager.as:193]
>       at spark.components::SkinnablePopUpContainer/open()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\SkinnablePopUpContainer.as:450]
>       at views::TodayResults/init()[C:\Google Drive\projects\android\ipad\src\views\TodayResults.mxml:27]
>       at views::TodayResults/___TodayResults_View1_creationComplete()[C:\Google Drive\projects\android\ipad\src\views\TodayResults.mxml:5]
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1818]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:842]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]

**Error line**

```
loadingScreen = new InitializePopUp();
loadingScreen.open(this,true); <-- error happens here
```

I am using Flex builder 4.6 and I'm creating a flex mobile AIR app

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?  And also, the line of code which the error occurs on?

Comment: Updated, and oddly enough if I add a textarea to the SkinnablePopUpContainer but on a second state it works